# How to connect to Cassandra using ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and was trying to achieve some simple
operations like inserting data into cassandra. I am using cassandra gem
to achieve this.

```
client = Cassandra.new('tags_logs', 'ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx.com:9160')
client.disable_node_auto_discovery!
client.get('tag_data','red')
```

And I get the following error:

```
ThriftClient::NoServersAvailable - No live servers in ...
```

I'm running this code from my local machine. And while I've **no problem** connecting using cassandra-cli  (so it is not a firewall issue), the code refuses to work. It **works perfectly** when accessing Cassandra on my own local machine.

Any ideas? 
Thanks,

Eden.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this gem I'm developing: https://github.com/hsgubert/cassandra_migrations

It gives access to Cassandra through CQL3 and manages schema with migrations.

Note: it requires Rails.

Answer (score 0):

For future generations: simply change the timeout ...

client = Cassandra.new('tags_logs', 'ec2-example-example-example.com:9160',:connect_timeout => 10000)